# Azure geo replication - recreating link on the same DB

Tags: sql, azure, geo-replication

We have a sql database on AZURE, which is geo replicated to another server in different location.

We had incorrect pricing tier on this DB (which also transfered to the geo replica). In order to change it, i had remove DB from failover group and then delete replication link.

Now when i want to recreate the link, it says that DB with this name already exists (which of course does, i deleted the link but not the replicated DB).

Is there any way to recreate link on the existing DB or is the best practise to just delete the replicated DB and create it anew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Geo Replication Failover is a feature designed for **automatically managing replications** on database failures.
If it were a manual exception, such as incorrect pricing or schema errors, it would not correct/reflect by default because those databases are **read-only**, as shown below.

[image]

Solution:

1.Delete the database on the replica and re-add the database from the primary server again; it will automatically configure the latest database features; there is no need to delete the link.

[image]

Step2:
Create a new replica link from primary to failover again
[image]

[image]